# Using Mono 4.0, does anyone know how to write to an open console i.e. /dev/pts/0?

Tags: c#, mono

I can't seem to figure out how to repeatedly write to a console such as /dev/pts/0 on CentOS 7.1.  What I'm trying to do is pipe commands to a process that is listening on a named pipe.  The process should be able to write some output back to a specified console.

Using `SerialPort` gives me an InvalidArguement exception which I assume means that it doesn't know about the pseudo terminal file type.

I tried `File.WriteAllText` and that works once and then when I send a second command on the pipe it gives me a Sharing violation on path /dev/pts/0.

I tried `File.AppendAllText` and I get an error the stream does not support seeking.

I tried using `FileStream` and I get Sharing violation on path /dev/pts/0 same as `WriteAllText`.

The code in the `echoCommand` function below shows what I'm doing with different options commented out:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.IO.Ports;

class PipeListener
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n***Named piper server example ***\n");        
        NamedPipeServerStream pipe = new NamedPipeServerStream("/tmp/test");
        pipe.WaitForConnection();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(pipe);
        int i = 0;
        String tty = "";
        String cmd = "";
        while(i < 10)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            tty = Command.getTTY(line);
            cmd = Command.getCommand(line);
            echoCommand(tty, cmd); 
            Console.WriteLine("Recevied command: " +line);
            i++;
        }
        pipe.Close();
    }

    public static void echoCommand(String tty, String command)
    {
        if (tty != "" && File.Exists(tty))
        {
            String output = String.Format("\nYour command was: {0}\n", command);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[output.Length * sizeof(char)];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(output.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, 
                                    bytes.Length);

            /*SerialPort port = new SerialPort(tty, 38400);
            port.Open();
            if (port.IsOpen)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Echoing command");
                port.Write(output);     
            }
            */

            //File.WriteAllText(tty, output);

            //File.AppendAllText(tty, output); 

            FileStream file = new FileStream(tty, FileMode.Open);
            file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }
}

class Command
{
    public static String getTTY(String str)
    {
        String[] words = str.Split(' ');
        return words[0];
    }

    public static String getCommand(String str)
    {
        String[] words = str.Split(' ');
        String[] cmd = new String[words.Length-1];
        Array.Copy(words,1,cmd,0, words.Length - 1);
        return String.Join(" ", cmd);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is with the FileStream.  When I restructure the code to only open the pts device once, I can write as many times as a like.  If I open the file, write, and then close and/or dispose of the FileStream in a loop, I get the sharing violation consistently.  It's like the FileStream doesn't release the file lock when it is closed.  I even tried sleeping after closing the FileStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was with the way I was using `FileStream`.  `FileStream` needs to open the  PTS using the correct file sharing.  I'll post my solution below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

class PipeListener
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n***Named piper server example ***\n");
        NamedPipeServerStream pipe = new NamedPipeServerStream("/tmp/test");
        pipe.WaitForConnection();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(pipe);
        int i = 0;
        String tty = "";
        String cmd = "";
        while(i < 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for pipe.");
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            tty = Command.getTTY(line);
            cmd = Command.getCommand(line);

            echoCommand(tty, cmd);
            Console.WriteLine("Recevied command: " +line);
            i++;
        }
        pipe.Close();
    }

    public static void echoCommand(String tty, String command)
    {
        if (tty != "" && File.Exists(tty))
        {
            String output = String.Format("\nYour command was: {0}\n", command);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[output.Length * sizeof(char)];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(output.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0,
                                    bytes.Length);

            FileStream term = new FileStream(tty, FileMode.Open,
                    FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write);

            term.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            term.Flush(true);
            term.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

class Command
{
    public static String getTTY(String str)
    {
        String[] words = str.Split(' ');
        return words[0];
    }

    public static String getCommand(String str)
    {
        String[] words = str.Split(' ');
        String[] cmd = new String[words.Length-1];
        Array.Copy(words,1,cmd,0, words.Length - 1);
        return String.Join(" ", cmd);
    }
}
```